# Unsupported index type: list error when converting columns from factors to numerics

Tags: r, error-handling

I am trying to convert a series of columns from factors to numerics. After running the 2nd line of code here, I get an error.

```
> cols.num<-c(df[19:59],df[75:94])
> df[cols.num] <- sapply(df[cols.num],as.numeric)
Error: Unsupported index type: list
```

How do I address this error so that I can convert the columns in cols.num to numeric variables?

Edit: This is an example of what some of the data looks like.

```
A1U_sweet  A2F_dip  A3U_bbq  C1U_sweet  C2F_dip  C3U_bbq  B1U_sweet  B2F_dip
1          2        1        NA         NA       NA       1          2
NA         NA       NA       4          1        2        4          1
2          4        7        NA         NA       NA       2          4
```

Comment: It looks like your `cols.num` is not what you want it to be, it's a list. Showing us some of your data would help.

Comment: @kgolyaev I added an example of what some of the data looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cols.num` should be a vector of column indexes. Instead, it is a list of values of the column.

Here is an example of the problem.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(15), ncol = 5))
df
#>          V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
#> 1 0.3539401 0.8420100 0.7615357 0.6313510 0.8367287
#> 2 0.7218828 0.4994062 0.8193055 0.9419635 0.3552728
#> 3 0.6302484 0.9259249 0.5634492 0.9034216 0.8514657

cols.num <- c(df[1:2],df[4:5])
df[cols.num] <- sapply(df[cols.num], as.integer)
#> Error in `[.default`(df, cols.num) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

If we look at `col.num`, it is a list of the column values.

```
cols.num
#> $V1
#> [1] 0.3539401 0.7218828 0.6302484
#> 
#> $V2
#> [1] 0.8420100 0.4994062 0.9259249
#> 
#> $V4
#> [1] 0.6313510 0.9419635 0.9034216
#> 
#> $V5
#> [1] 0.8367287 0.3552728 0.8514657
```

To fix it, just create a vector of the column indexes.

```
cols.num <- c(1:2, 4:5)
df[cols.num] <- sapply(df[cols.num], as.integer)
df
#>   V1 V2        V3 V4 V5
#> 1  0  0 0.7615357  0  0
#> 2  0  0 0.8193055  0  0
#> 3  0  0 0.5634492  0  0
```

Comment: This worked! Just curious: is there a reason you changed as.numeric to as.integer?

Comment: I changed it purely for the example. Just so that it would show what columns changed. If it changed a numeric to numeric, it wouldn't show any difference.